# Rename excel sheets with SQL Server Report Builder 2008 2.0

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008, worksheet, report-builder2.0

I know you can name excel sheets with Report Builder 2008 2.0 R2 but I was wondering there was a way to do it in Report Builder 2008 2.0? Any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this isn't possible; that feature was introduced in R2 specifically in response to user requests.